# Is there any way of making a causation matrix, much like the correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, causality

So I have a bunch of parameters say $X_i \in \mathbb{X}$, where $i\in \{0,1,2...N\}$ . Now, I can find the correlation between any two features $i,j$ and get a matrix $\mathbb{C} = \text{Corr}(X,X)$.

But if I need to find the causation say between any feature $i,j$ i.e. if $i$ occur due to $j$ or not etc.

1. How can I do that mathematically?
2. Also, how to represent it mathematically (much like correlation values of 0 to 1)?

Comment: Well, first we need an accepted quantification of causation. There is none but for the sake of argument let's say it is [Transfer Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_entropy). Then we need to normalise it across the variables in our sample. Again, a bit fuzzy but can be done. We have to also smooth out some little niggles like the fact our matrix will be non-symmetric. And then we have a "causation matrix". Read on Information & Transfer Entropy first, then revisit this.

Comment: @usεr11852 Couldn't you also define the $ij$ entry as $P(X_i|\operatorname{do}(X_j))?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister, I wonder what $P(X_i)$ stands for and what properties it has (keeping in mind it is an element of a matrix "much like a correlation matrix"). user11852, I am not familiar with transfer entropy from before, but it does not seem it is a causal concept.

Comment: @usεr11852 Does using transfer entropy for this lead one to conclude that chocolate rabbits and painted eggs cause Easter?

Comment: The structural causal model for $x_{i}\to x_{j}$ is potentially different for every pair of variables (so the computational cost would likely be much higher than for a correlation matrix). If you are explicitly temporally ordering variable measures, you have the benefit of needing only the lower (or upper) triangle of the matrix; the matrix would otherwise be asymmetric since, unlike correlation, causation is directional. Finally, you need to think about what the diagonal means: some causal formalisms admit 'self-effects' (i.e. $x_i \to x_i$), and some do not.

Comment: Final aside: the **community effect matrix** of Levins' [qualitative loop analysis](https://www.academia.edu/download/50256413/j.1749-6632.1974.tb20562.x20161111-9773-8soz.pdf) (and [extensions](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hiram-Li/publication/10664402_Qualitative_Stability_and_Ambiguity_in_Model_Ecosystems/links/0046353601e3887f53000000/Qualitative-Stability-and-Ambiguity-in-Model-Ecosystems.pdf) to it, e.g., by Dambacher) are causal effect matrices (but they use a very different formalism that Granger causality, or counterfactual formal causal models).

Comment: @RichardHardy It's just the probability that variable $X_i$ will take on value $x_i$ given that we force $X_j$ to equal $x_j.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister, first, $x_i$ is nowhere to be found in the notation. Second, unless $X_i$ is binary, the probability is not that informative. Third, if $X_i$ is continuous, the probability is zero. Thus my question and my doubts.

Comment: @dimitriy: We have Granger causality for that. :) (More seriously: if I thought TE was the good answer I would have written/expanded my comment to an answer. I don't think it is, thus no  answer.)

Comment: @usεr11852, I guess it was a joke, but in case it was not, I have commented elsewhere on Cross Validated explaining how chocolate bunnies do not Granger-cause Easter and such. Granger causality is sophisticated enough not to produce such ridiculous results. This is due to it being about *incremental* predictive power of lagged $X$ for $Y$ *beyond* lagged values of $Y$ itself. Granger causality is more than lagged cross correlation.

Comment: @RichardHardy: It is mostly a joke, yes. But Dimitriy does raise a valid concern. Regarding the use of TE in causality: I have seen it a few times in the past, I don't remember the exact references from that time but here is a quick one: [Quantifying ‘Causality’ in Complex Systems: Understanding Transfer Entropy](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0099462). (At some point in my life I was very interested in Information Entropy and related concepts.)

Comment: I now think I have written about other festivals, not Easter in particular. Easter is a likely a good example where one could get trapped without a really long time series.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Apologies my do-Calculus understanding is rudimentary but as Richard pointed out, what you describe looks very much like a is a distribution-like object. We are looking for a scalar-like object; I guess taking a MAP could suffice? - but we would also need to define relevant priors.